# is ROSOUT_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING available in melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu melodic.

*The specific question is:*

Is the use of flag [ROSOUT_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1425) available for me?
My system says about ros-comm package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -s ros-melodic-ros-comm | grep Version
Version: 1.14.3-0bionic.20181112.202811
```

*The general question is:*

How can I relate the version of a given Ubuntu ROS package to the changes I can see in the ROS package git repo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317030/is-rosout_disable_file_logging-available-in-melodic?/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2019-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-28**:
Just an observation: `dpkg` is not a command that requires super user rights. `sudo` is not necessary there.

Note also that for ROS packages, you could use the `rosversion` command:

```
$ rosversion roscpp
1.14.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am running Ubuntu melodic.
>
> *The specific question is:*
>
> Is the use of flag [ROSOUT_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1425) available for me?
> My system says about ros-comm package:
>
> ```
> $ sudo dpkg -s ros-melodic-ros-comm | grep Version
> Version: 1.14.3-0bionic.20181112.202811
> ```

As of right now (ie: 2019-02-28) my answer/assumption would be: no, not on a system that installs ROS from the `.deb` packages provided by the OSRF buildfarm. `roscpp` has not seen a Melodic release since 2018-08-06, which is two days (2018-08-08) before [ros/ros_comm#1425](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1425) was merged.

The changelog for Melodic can be found here: [ros/ros_comm/clients/roscpp/CHANGELOG.rst](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/melodic-devel/clients/roscpp/CHANGELOG.rst) (note: this is not a permalink, on purpose). You can find the latest release in there, at the top of the list.

The commit date of the merge of [ros/ros_comm#1425](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1425) can be seen at the bottom of the GH page for that PR, or on [ros/ros_comm@678ad4f2](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/678ad4f239926111c7684c20f39ed91644aa1c13) or from the commit itself (`git show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%cd' 678ad4f2399`).

> *The general question is:*

> How can I relate the version of a given Ubuntu ROS package to the changes I can see in the ROS package git repo?

It's most likely easiest to read the changelog of a package (note that those are also accessible from the wiki: [here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/changelogs/roscpp/changelog.html) for `roscpp` in Melodic fi and in `/usr/share/doc/ros-kinetic-roscpp` on Ubuntu/Debian systems). As above (in the answer to your specific question), lookup the PR number or description for the change and match it with the version section headings.

If the package is hosted as a `git` repository (and `ros_comm` is) then an alternative could be to use `git` itself. The version nrs of ROS pkgs on your machine are derived from the git tags that were created as part of the release process.

A crude way to find the tag that "contains" a specific commit would be (where `$HASH` is the commit hash of the change you're looking for):

```
git tag --contains $HASH
```

For `ros/ros_comm#1425` that doesn't return anything (as there hasn't been a release with that yet), but just as an example (I chose a random other PR that *was* included in a Melodic release):

```
git tag --contains ea850205e87
```

returns:

```
1.14.0
1.14.1
1.14.2
1.14.3
```

which tells us that the merge commit for [ros/ros_comm#1393](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1393) is included in 4 releases and appeared first in `1.14.0`.

The same information can be gleaned from the GH page for that commit ([ros/ros_comm@ea850205](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/ea850205e87ff0d56a6eeec95d119a8a7399ee11)):

[image: github page for ea850205 showing tags 'containing' it]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1